# How I Can Get Users Coordinates swift

Tags: swift, gps, location, label, coordinates

I want to get the user coordinates and want to print them out in a label.

How I can do that? I want to do that in Swift.

Bye
Henry

Comment: Is this for iOS, macOS, or Linux? Please do some basic research and try something. Update your question with what you've tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you don't know how to get the coordinates!?

You should make an `imageView` and then in your `ViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var coordinates = CGPoint.zero

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
        coordinates = touch.location(in: imageView)
        print(coordinates)
        textLabel.text = "\(coordinates)"
    }
}
```

Then you will print the coordinates and can put them in to a label.

Comment: The tags on this question are more related to location-based coordinates - not touch coordinates.

Comment: I've done it a little differently now, but I have a new problem: when I write:  "locationLabel.text = location.coordinate" then there is an error:          
"Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to type 'String?'"

Comment: Yes that Work, but no it shows all:                    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.90864086268193, longitude: 11.277828585042514) How I can remove the first part?

Comment: if you add latitude and longitude and make it in to two you will have it nicely written. `locationLabel.text = ("\(location.coordinate.latitude) \(location.coordinate.longitude)")`

Comment: What just happened? Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question? Why are people up voting this answer? Why was this answer accepted?